# Calculating Overall Median from Multiple Files Using GNU parallel

Tags: bash, median, gnu-parallel

I have the following command:

`find 01/ -type f -name '*.csv.gz' | parallel "pigz -dc {} | datamash -t, median 3"`

This command, for each .csv.gz file found in the '01/' directory, decompresses the file and calculates the median of the values in the third column of each file. However, I'm looking to calculate the overall median across all files rather than the median for each file individually.

P.S. I've tried running:

`find 01/ -type f -name '*.csv.gz' | parallel "pigz -dc {} | datamash -t, median 3" | datamash median 1`

But this seems to provide the "median of medians" which is not the result I'm seeking.

Comment: I'm not sure you can calculate a global median by looking at summaries of subsets. I'm also not sure that running a program (`pigz`) that is already parallel under `parallel` gains much.

Comment: maybe just try: `find 01/ -type f -name '*.csv.gz' -exec pigz -dc {} + | datamash -t, median 3`

Comment: how big is the dataset? a quick test (`seq 100000001 | datamash -t, median 1` / `seq 200000001 | datamash -t, median 1`) shows memory usage that grows with input size and no obvious use of temp files to limit it. you may need an alternative approach if data doesn't fit in ram.

Comment: @jhnc You're right. The performance of pigz and gzip for a single file is quite similar.

Answer (score 3):

This is really a comment, but too long.

To get the exact median of n numbers you need O(n) space. This is because if The Devil designs the input, he can force any place in the sequence to be the median, and you will have no way of ruling out any place until you have read at least n/2 numbers.

If, however, The Devil has *not* designed the input, and the input is more or less random or normally distributed, then we can get the correct value most of the time using Remedian (Rousseeuw, Peter J., and Gilbert W. Bassett Jr. "The remedian: A robust averaging method for large data sets." Journal of the American Statistical Association 85.409 (1990): 97-104). Remedian uses O(1) space.

GNU Parallel uses Remedian internally in `set_remedian`; and yes: It really is only ~10 lines of code.

https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/src/parallel#n14377

So I would run something like:

```
find 01/ -type f -name '*.csv.gz' -exec pigz -dc {} + | awk '{print $3}' | remedian
```

where `remedian` is your implementation of Remedian.